# Can Shopify be installed in xampp or any other web hosting server?

Tags: php, xampp, shopify

I heard of Shopify couple of days ago, when I got a project in my office regarding Shopify, and I did a lot of research over this CMS, but I'm still unable to know that can Shopify be installed on xampp and can we customize this CMS with respect to development aspects?

Comment: http://www.shopify.com/faq/how-do-i-install-shopify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it can not. Because shopify is a hosted solution (SaaS), so you can not download it, you can only create an account on their site.

As mentioned on their site (pointed out by deceze):

> Shopify is web based ecommerce software. This means there’s no installation required and it works with all operating systems (including Windows and MacOS)! We host Shopify so you don’t have to worry about installing, upgrading or maintaining any software or web servers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run a local copy of Shopify, but you can set up a test shop and you can copy products between live and test shops.  Themes can also be copied.  This provides a very nice development environment.  There is also the Shopify Theme tool which lets you have a local copy of a theme that synchs back to Shopify when you save files.

Comment: What happens when I save the local copy, it will affect directly on the live?